# How to display contents within a MySQL database through an html file?

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, database

Is it possible to open an html file, have it send some signal to a server-side application to query data from a mysql db and then return that data to that original html file? So instead of having some php or js program spit out an html file, can i create an 'index.html' file that when i click on, will display contents of my db? Thanks

Comment: No, you need some sort of programming language to interact with your database, html is just a markup language

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid but is it possible to attach a nodejs program to an html file's (eg 'index.html') script tag that connects to the db, outputs the queried values from the db, then saves that outputted value into something the html file can print out?

Comment: I'm sure there is, I don't use node.js personally... I would just make an Ajax request on the html page and return a JSON object and then print that out however you fancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is limited to using only HTML, then this is not possible.

---

If you mean only using a static HTML page (allowing inline JavaScript), then there are lots of ways you could do what you want.

You could use client side JavaScript, served in a static page removing the need to run a backend like Node JS or some other kind of non static web server.

Something like this for your static HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Using Fetch</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // Fetch your information here using client side JavaScript
        // Do something
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Your server side application can expose an endpoint that outputs some JSON, we will use the endpoint `https://example.com/api/` and fetch it using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
let url = 'https://example.com/api/';

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then((data) => {
  // Your data is in the variable 'data', do something with it
})
.catch(err => { throw err });
```

---

All together your HTML file could look something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Using Fetch</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="data"></p>
    <script>
           let url = 'https://example.com/api/';
           fetch(url)
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then((data) => {
             document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = data;
           })
           .catch(err => { throw err });         
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

That code is a basic example of getting some data from an endpoint and setting a paragraph on your page to show that information.